# extract figures from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

Feel free to tell me to go away and read the documentation but I'm in a bit of a rush.

Am using postgres access in node.js to extract telephone system data, namely call duration for an office wallboard.

I've run my client query filtering by outgoing calls for a specific user on a specific date for example and put the results into a variable which prints as an array in the console

```
Connected
┌─────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ (index) │                  call_time                   │
├─────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│    0    │             PostgresInterval {}              │
│    1    │ PostgresInterval { minutes: 1, seconds: 31 } │
│    2    │ PostgresInterval { minutes: 1, seconds: 8 }  │
│    3    │ PostgresInterval { minutes: 2, seconds: 5 }  │
│    4    │       PostgresInterval { seconds: 50 }       │
│    5    │ PostgresInterval { minutes: 2, seconds: 3 }  │
└─────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────┘
[
  { call_time: PostgresInterval {} },
  { call_time: PostgresInterval { minutes: 1, seconds: 31 } },
  { call_time: PostgresInterval { minutes: 1, seconds: 8 } },
  { call_time: PostgresInterval { minutes: 2, seconds: 5 } },
  { call_time: PostgresInterval { seconds: 50 } },
  { call_time: PostgresInterval { minutes: 2, seconds: 3 } }
]
Disconnected
```

I'm only interested in the minute and second numbers so 1 and 31 from first result for instance.

Is there a simple way to just get the numbers out of this array?

the code I'm using to get the data is

```
execute()
async function execute(){
  await client.connect()
  console.log("Connected")
  const results = await client.query("SELECT call_time FROM call_history_view WHERE src_dn ='207' and call_history_view.segment_start_time > current_date - interval '2 days'")
  console.table(results.rows)
  var resultData = results.rows
  console.log(resultData)
  await client.end()
  console.log("Disconnected")
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `PostgresInterval` is preventing this from being a proper JSON. Is that the actual thing you're getting when logging `resultData` to the console?

Comment: Hi Fiddling, I see. Yes, the top section is what actually shows in the console.

Comment: What happens if you do this after getting the results? `var resultData = results.rows.map(row => { return { call_time: row.call_time.toString() }; }); console.log(resultData);` Is `PostgresInterval` gone from the console?

Comment: Yes, it now reads:
[
  { call_time: '[object Object]' },
  { call_time: '[object Object]' },
  { call_time: '[object Object]' },
  { call_time: '[object Object]' },
  { call_time: '[object Object]' },
  { call_time: '[object Object]' }
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

First let's get rid of the `PostgresInterval`, to make the result a parseable JSON.

```
execute()
async function execute(){
  await client.connect()
  console.log("Connected")
  const results = await client.query("SELECT call_time FROM call_history_view WHERE src_dn ='207' and call_history_view.segment_start_time > current_date - interval '2 days'")
  console.table(results.rows)
  //var resultData = results.rows
  var resultData = results.rows.map(row => {
    const minutes = ('minutes' in row.call_time) ? row.call_time.minutes : 0;
    const seconds = ('seconds' in row.call_time) ? row.call_time.seconds : 0;
    return { call_time: { minutes, seconds } };
  });
  console.log(resultData);
  /*
  should display something along the lines of
  [
    { call_time: { minutes: 0, seconds: 0 } },
    { call_time: { minutes: 1, seconds: 31 } },
    { call_time: { minutes: 1, seconds: 8 } },
    { call_time: { minutes: 2, seconds: 5 } },
    { call_time: { minutes: 0, seconds: 50 } },
    { call_time: { minutes: 2, seconds: 3 } }
  ]
  */
  await client.end()
  console.log("Disconnected")
}
```

Mapping does the following:

- goes through each of the entries within `results.rows`
- checks if the current item (`call_time`) as a set `minutes` key
- if it doesn't, it sets it, and assigns it the value of 0
- repeats the same for seconds

After that, we have something that can be parsed, like in the following snippet.

```js
let calls = [
  { call_time: { minutes: 0, seconds: 0 } },
  { call_time: { minutes: 1, seconds: 31 } },
  { call_time: { minutes: 1, seconds: 8 } },
  { call_time: { minutes: 2, seconds: 5 } },
  { call_time: { minutes: 0, seconds: 50 } },
  { call_time: { minutes: 2, seconds: 3 } }
];

calls.forEach(function(singleCall) {
    let call_time = singleCall.call_time;
    if(Object.keys(call_time).length != 0) {
        console.log(call_time);
    }
});
```

If you need to extract `minutes` or `seconds`, you would do something like this:

```
console.log(call_time.minutes);
console.log(call_time.seconds);
```

---

Since this suggestion adds something to an originally empty object (the first `call_time` entry in your question), if you don't want that entry to show up, you can filter the `resultData` array, like so:

```js
let calls = [
  { call_time: { minutes: 0, seconds: 0 } },
  { call_time: { minutes: 1, seconds: 31 } },
  { call_time: { minutes: 1, seconds: 8 } },
  { call_time: { minutes: 2, seconds: 5 } },
  { call_time: { minutes: 0, seconds: 50 } },
  { call_time: { minutes: 2, seconds: 3 } }
];

calls = calls.filter(function(call) {
    return (call.call_time.minutes > 0 || call.call_time.seconds > 0);
})

console.log(calls);
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience Fiddling, took a little bit of time for me to get my lesser mind around this :-), but it works, thank you for your rare genius and for taking the time to put all this together. Very much appreciated.